# Count relationship pairs in Neo4j

Tags: java, nosql, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm starting dealing with Neo4j so I'm not really proficient on this topic. In figure below I have 2-mode (bipartite) graph where green node presents "document" and red node presents "term" which occur in particular document. (Real-world graph is actually huge: about 20.000.000 documents and 25.000 terms).

I wonder how I go about counting co-occurrence pairs of terms in neo4j (in Cypher or Java). The desired output from query should be:

```
# Example: Pair (term-1, term-2) occurs in doc-1 and in doc-3
# Frequency for pair (term-1, term-2) should be 2
# termA | term B | frequency
term-1 | term-2 | 2
term-1 | term-3 | 1
term-2 | term-3 | 2
```

[image: Bipartite graph]

Graph is available at http://console.neo4j.org/r/7fmo7c

**Code to reproduce test graph in Neo4j**

```
set name root
mkrel -t ROOT -c -v
cd 1
set name doc-1
set type document
mkrel -t HAVE -cv
cd 2
set name term-1
set type term
cd ..
mkrel -t HAVE -cv
cd 3
set name term-2
set type term
cd ..
mkrel -t HAVE -cv
cd 4
set name term-3
set type term
mkrel -t HAVE -d INCOMING -c
cd 5
set name doc-2
set type document
mkrel -t HAVE -d OUTGOING -n 3
cd 3
mkrel -t HAVE -d INCOMING -c
cd 6
set name doc-3
set type document
mkrel -t HAVE -d OUTGOING -n 2
```

**Code to reproduce test graph in Java**

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.DynamicRelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings;

public class CountPairs {
    private static final String DB_PATH = "test.db";
    private static GraphDatabaseService graphDb;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().
                newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(DB_PATH).
                setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable, "name, type").
                setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing, "true").
                newGraphDatabase();

        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        Node doc1, doc2, doc3 = null;
        Node term1, term2, term3 = null;
        Relationship rel1, rel2, rel3, rel4, rel5, rel6, rel7 = null;
        try
        {
            // Create nodes
            doc1 = graphDb.createNode();
            doc2 = graphDb.createNode();
            doc3 = graphDb.createNode();
            term1 = graphDb.createNode();
            term2 = graphDb.createNode();
            term3 = graphDb.createNode();
            // Set properties
            doc1.setProperty("name", "doc1");
            doc1.setProperty("type", "document");
            doc2.setProperty("name", "doc2");
            doc2.setProperty("type", "document");
            doc3.setProperty("name", "doc3");
            doc3.setProperty("type", "document");
            // Set properties
            term1.setProperty("name", "term1");
            term1.setProperty("type", "term");
            term2.setProperty("name", "term2");
            term2.setProperty("type", "term");
            term3.setProperty("name", "term3");
            term3.setProperty("type", "term");
            // Create relations
            rel1 = doc1.createRelationshipTo(term1, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("HAVE"));
            rel2 = doc1.createRelationshipTo(term2, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("HAVE"));
            rel3 = doc1.createRelationshipTo(term3, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("HAVE"));
            rel4 = doc2.createRelationshipTo(term2, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("HAVE"));
            rel5 = doc2.createRelationshipTo(term3, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("HAVE"));
            rel6 = doc3.createRelationshipTo(term1, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("HAVE"));
            rel7 = doc3.createRelationshipTo(term2, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("HAVE"));

            tx.success();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            tx.failure();
        }
        finally
        {
            tx.finish();
        }

        graphDb.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest creating and sharing the test graph on console.neo4j.org rather than providing code to generate test graph. It would be very helpful and its very easy to create one.

Comment: Added. URL is http://console.neo4j.org/r/7fmo7c.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me to quickly play with it and get closer to what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
start t1=node(*), t2=node(*) 
where has(t1.type) and has(t2.type) and t1.type='term' and t2.type='term' and id(t1) < id(t2)
with t1, t2 
match t1<-[:HAVE]-doc-[:HAVE]->t2 
where doc.type='document' 
return t1, t2, count(doc)
```

You can try this here : http://console.neo4j.org/r/pshvqx

I hope this is what you want. Further, for better performance, I would suggest you to put index on nodes of type 'term' and use index in the start clause to get *t1* and *t2*

Comment: Or have a `where id(t1) < id(t2)`.

Comment: Excellent idea @ThomasFenzl !!! Thanks a lot. That didn't strike me at all. Updating answer with same.

Comment: This works like a charm, but I have problems with indexes. I don't know exactly where (and how) to put indexes. I started with `start t1=node:node_auto_index('type:*')...`, but doesn't seem to works.

Comment: if you have enabled auto indexing later, it won't work for existing data. In such case you need to manually add existing nodes to auto index or recreate the data. Also make sure you have defined the properties to be auto indexed in neo4j.properties. For details refer http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/auto-indexing.html#auto-indexing-config

Comment: Also note that auto index is read only index i.e. once added to index, you cannot remove an entry from it. Go for auto indexing only if this is ok for you.

Comment: I use auto indexing for testing purpose only. `neo4j.properties` file is set to index `id`, `name` and `type` fields. I recreate data using clause: `START n=node(*) WHERE HAS(n.type) SET n.type=n.type`. Command `index --indexes` returns `node_auto_index` index. The main issue now is how to modify your clause to get t1 and t2.

Comment: Try if this works: `start t1=node:node_auto_index(type='term')`